# Timer is triggering event on another instance of my Form

Tags: c#, timer, callback

I have multiple instances of the same dialog.  I pass in an enum so that the dialog knows what information to display.  I have timers within my Form that trigger actions (in this case a button click for an example).  However, when these timers trigger, they get caught by only one (and always the last Form created) and not the other Forms.  I would like the Form that triggered the timer to catch it.  What am I missing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public enum Animal { CAT, DOG, PIG };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form2 F21 = new Form2(Animal.CAT);
        F21.Show();

        Form2 F22 = new Form2(Animal.DOG);
        F22.Show();

        Form2 F23 = new Form2(Animal.PIG);
        F23.Show();
    }

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int buttonCount = 0;
    Form1.Animal Animal;
    private static System.Threading.Timer refreshListViewTimer;

    public Form2(Form1.Animal TheAnimal)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Animal = TheAnimal;
        Text = TheAnimal.ToString();
        refreshListViewTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnRefreshListTimer);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshListViewTimer.Change(50, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void OnRefreshListTimer(object sender)
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
            Invoke(new RefreshListDelegate(this.RefreshList), new object[] { });
    }

    private delegate void RefreshListDelegate();
    private void RefreshList()
    {
        buttonCount++;
        Text = this.Animal.ToString() + " " + buttonCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

In this case, no matter which Form I click the button, the PIG dialog will always be incremented.

Comment: Review your favorite C# language book for the meaning of the *static* keyword.

Comment: Ah crap!  This dialog used to be single use and was just updated to allow multiple types.  Thanks a lot for that catch!!!